# Adding Angular 2 & Webpack to an existing server/client folder structure

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I currently have the following folder structure:

root

 - client

 - server

Inside my server folder I have an express app running with mongoose and mongodb and this is acting purely as a Web API.

What I am trying to do is set up a Angular 2 project within the `client` folder. I've read up on some tricks such as `angular-cli` but I don't want to scaffold the whole project but instead only the `src` folder. I would like to have webpack and loaders for `sass` and `typescript`.

What are some recommendations with how I can tackle this issue?

PS: I didn't want to use a generator since I feel like it would take away from my learning curve a little. But my next project I can see how beneficial those things are!

Thanks

Comment: HI nav. It depends on which type of server you are running it on. If it's an IIS server then rename your dist folder (the app build for production) to `wwwroot` (or something like that). If i were you, i would seperate the Angular app and the server when developing and then, as mentioned, copy the dist folder to the server when "publishing". I hope some of it made sense.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have a limitation with the client that they both have to reside under the `root`. I am using the MEAN stack, so I won't be using IIS as my webserver at this moment.

Comment: My point was that you just have to put your dist folder in the root directory of the server. What the folder should be named varies from server to server. I will however recommend that you use the angular-cli.

Answer (score 0):

I very recently did the same thing for learning purpose, used Webpack instead of `angular-cli`.

What I did was mostly to use these as a starting point:

- https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter
- https://github.com/damnko/angular2-instagram

If you want to have a look at mine, you can find it here https://github.com/damnko/angular2-django-movies and it has the same structure as yours.

Unfortunately there's not much to say since there are many steps involved, but the core things are the `karma` and `webpack` configuration settings, the folder structure, the core module and app component.

Hope this helps